# Google on different versions of games

Tags: unity, android, marketing, google-play

I'm focusing on a game for the Android platform, and thinking of building multiple versions with different themes. Every one of them would have a distinct name, graphics, and content, but the same game engine.

I would be maintaining the same code base for these 20 apps. If I capitalize on this format with different themes, is that forbidden in Google play?

Comment: Why would you be banned for using the same engine?

Comment: Same logic different content

Answer (score 2):

It is not forbidden by Google play. I have published several games using the same game engine. They don't have a problem with it. In fact, the game engine is one I modified from a book and I know that many people have published games using the same engine.

Look at lgdx -- many people are publishing using basically the same underlying code.

Alternatively, look at 'Choices' -- they acknowledge the 'sameness' of the engine with different content.

Comment: It is worth addressing that Unity, itself, is a game engine. Disallowing mutiple games with the same engine voids the entire point of using Unity to make an android game for the store, in the first place.